# how can i get the selected value of dropdown list in php?

Tags: php, html

i have seen several question but i can not find any answer?
 i am add a some value to dropdown through the loop and want to show the  value when i select one value from dropdown box .but i can not find .

```
  $items[] = $file ;
  echo '<select name="value">';
  foreach($items as $video){ 
    echo  '<option value="' . $video . '">' . $video . '</option>' ;
  }
  echo '</select>';
  $value = $_GET['footage'];
```

How can I get the value when I select some value in the dropdown box.

Comment: this doesn't help `$GET_` read up on superglobals http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php and check for errors

Comment: reload my comment, I added a link

Comment: never mind, you fixed the syntax error

Comment: @TOM surround your select with a `form` and then when an option is selected, submit the form and use `$_GET` or `$_POST` to retrieve and display the value (based on what kind of submit the `form` is doing).

Comment: Do you want to show the value as soon as the user selects something? Do you have a FORM tag somewhere? Is the form even submitted to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `HTML selected` attribute to `<select>`

```
$value = $_GET['footage']; /* typo*/
 $items[] = $file ;
  echo '<select name="value">';
  foreach($items as $video){ 
    $selected = ($value == $video) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    echo  '<option value="' . $video . '"' . $selected . '>' . $video . '</option>' ;
  }

  echo'</select>';
```